# C# find all words equal except 2 characters

Tags: string, c#-4.0, character

I like to find all words in a List string equal input word, but 2 characters has variation. I like to find all words equal:

xxxV1xxx;
xxxV2xxx;
xxxV3xxx;...

I do not care if the word include V1, V2, V3; but has to have the same characters before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mystring.StartsWith("xxx") && mystring.EndsWith("xxx")

Here is an example:

```
      string[] str = { "xxxv1xxx", "xxxV2xxx", "xxxv3xxx", "xxv4xx", "xxV5xxx"};

      foreach (string s in str)
      {
        if( s.StartsWith("xxx") && s.EndsWith("xxx"))
            Console.WriteLine(s); //do whatever you want here
      }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/STnyWE